# Error: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I get the error below using VBA and Microsoft Excel.

> The following error Occured Either BOF or EOF is True , or the Current
> record has been deleted . Requested Operation requires a current
> record

How should I rewrite the code to avoid this error?

This is the code:

```
'below statement will execute the query and stores the Records in DBrs
    DBrs.Open DBQuery, DBcon
    If DBrs.EOF = True Then 'to check if any record then

' Spread all the records with all the columns
' in your sheet from Cell A2 onward.
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A23").CopyFromRecordset DBrs

'Above statement puts the data only but no column
'name. hence the below for loop will put all the
'column names in your excel sheet.
        For intColIndex = 0 To DBrs.Fields.Count - 1  ' recordset fields
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, intColIndex + 1).Value = DBrs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
        Next
    End If
'Close the connection
    DBcon.Close
    MsgBox "Generated Successfully"
    Exit Sub
    
err:
    MsgBox "Following Error Occurred: " & vbNewLine & err.Description
    DBcon.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What line does arise the error?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the types of objects involved, "Either BOF or EOF is True" sounds like a given if your `If` condition checks for `EOF = True`.

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns - getting at EOF = True

Comment: EOF means no current record, yet you're trying to copy from the recordset. Change to `If Not DBrs.EOF Then`.

Comment: It is unclear where your error occurs. Basically if it happens after `copyfromrecordset` it is likely similar to the fact that `recordset.getrows` iterates to the end of the recordset. Possibly `copyfromrecordset` does the same. Setting a `dbrs.movefirst` after copying would fix this.

Comment: As you stated yourself, you should to check for _both_ BOF and EOF, e.g. `If Not (DBrs.BOF And DBrs.EOF) Then ...`.

Comment: please correct the above code @Hel O'Ween

Comment: There's no need to test for both- if EOF is true when you've just opened a recordset it must be a null set.

Comment: I don't think that (=recordset must be NULL if EOF is True) is true.  As @Oliver pointed out, there might have occured an (implicit) action meanwhile, that positioned the cursor to the end of the recordset. But if both BOF and EOF are true, the recordset holds no records.

Comment: @Hel O'Ween how do I get rid of this issue bro

Comment: @perkenorde: I don't know what you want me to correct other than what I suggested. Replace your `If` statement in your code with mine.